# Music from windows 7 to iPhone 6 without itunes

Tags: music

I have a large number of songs I want to download from win7 to my iphone6, 
What is the easiest way? I don't have iTunes on this computer.

Answer (score -1):

It would be great to have file-access to iDevices, there appears to have been a lot of work done to make this difficult or nearly impossible from proprietary cords on up to inscrutable DB's. It seems unfair to pay so much for the products yet have such a trivial thing as open file access blocked so thoroughly and with such malicious intent! This, not just st for music files, but for ALL files.

I have seen two workarounds over the years -- one created a special driver that was used for low-level access to the entire storage device and created its own database with entries for every (music) file. The other method was to set up an FTP server using tFTP - an insecure and pretty featureless protocol.

Comment: not sure someone anonymously came along and gave a -1. Mine was the only answer and it is correct. apple blocks users from open access to their own files. It's bad practice, but people accept it and even pay extra. None of that is based on opinion....